# I want to convert NSString to NSDate but UIPickerView shows current date

Tags: iphone, nsdate

I want to convert NSString to NSDate  but UIPickerView shows current

```
datedatePicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
            datePicker.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
            datePicker.minuteInterval=5;
            NSLog(@"Date");
            ////////
            NSString *curDate=alarmData.date;
            //Jan 14, 2011 11:37
            NSDateFormatter *format = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
            [format setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];


        //Optionally for time zone converstions
        [format setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:nil]];

        NSDate  *da = [format dateFromString:curDate];

        [datePicker setDate:da animated:YES];
```

any suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Ali try this and u will get the string from date

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm"];

    //conversion of NSString to NSDate

    NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
    dateFromString = [formatter dateFromString:curDate];
    [formatter release];
```