# Converting ex. 2009-12-31T00:00:00.0000000-05:00 format to NSDate

Tags: iphone, nsdate, w3c

I am working with getting data from webservice in iPhone app and getting a date in format 2009-12-31T00:00:00.0000000-05:00.. How can I convert this to NSDate.. Please help....

Answer (score 2):

The problem with this format is that the `-05:00` format is not supported by `NSDateFormatter` date formats.

[Unicode date format patterns](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns) says it supports `-0500` though. You may have to manually strip the colon out of the timezone and then parse it using the format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.0000000ZZZ` (or maybe `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZ`)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688944/i-want-to-convert-nsstring-to-nsdate-but-uipickerview-shows-current-date/4689025#4689025) and try taking your date in string format...the convert it to `NSDate`