# How to convert string like 2012-08-01T11:53:58+02:00 into date in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

I am receiving a date string in a **JSON encoding** like this: **2012-08-01T11:53:58+02:00**. I would like to convert it into a **NSDate** object, **however my conversion isn't working**. As far as I know, it is supposed to be ISO 8601 format, but I am quite confused about the time zone at the end, because it has a colone in between.

My Code so far looks like this:

```
 /*
  * format the time
  */
 NSDateFormatter *isoDateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
 [isoDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
 NSDate *dateTmp = [isoDateFormatter dateFromString:[data objectForKey:@"datetimeServer"]];
 /*
  * log the output
  */
 [isoDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
 NSLog(@"Server time is %@", [isoDateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTmp]);
```

**To prevent unusable answers, the date is definitely there, I checked :) in the log.** But have Server time equals to (null), so the conversion didn't work correctly.

Thank you for your answers.

Bye,
Filip

Comment: Remove the colon from the timezone (`+02:00` to `+0200`). Then parse the date. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757797/converting-ex-2009-12-31t000000-0000000-0500-format-to-nsdate/4757974#4757974

Comment: Yep, remove the colon from the timezone.  Then NSDateFormatter will be able to parse it.

Comment: Yes that was the problem. The thing in my code was, that the method really didn't get the string correctly. My really really stupid mistake, I hate myself.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the a date string that you are receiving in a JSON encoding (as you mentioned) is like this: 2012-08-01T11:53:58+02:00 I am afraid that the date string is not in proper format  so i suggest you do a little bit of string manipulation.

//NSMutableString *string=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"2012-08-01T11:53:58+02:00"];

```
NSMutableString *string=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:[data objectForKey:@"datetimeServer"]]; 
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:@"+" options:NSBackwardsSearch]; 
[string insertString:@"GMT" atIndex:range.location];

NSDateFormatter *isoDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[isoDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"];
NSDate *dateTmp = [isoDateFormatter dateFromString:string];
NSLog(@"Server time is %@", dateTmp);

[isoDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd 'T' HH:mm:ss"];    
NSLog(@"Server time is %@", [isoDateFormatter stringFromDate:dateTmp]);
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Would you mind posting the reason for the negative vote? Thank you